# Submenu alignment using html css

Tags: html, css

First of all, I am just a beginner with web development. Was trying out my hand on a website with a horizontal main menu and a vertical submenu.

When I hover over a list item in the main menu, the submenu drops down & displaces the other elements of the main menu. Also the other issue is that the submenu does not align with the main menu list item.

This is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/mCvct/1/

Have been trying to do this since a while & have been looking at some solutions. But could not fix this so far.

Code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">SERVICES</a>

            <div class="subnavi">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">service1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">service2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">service3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- end of subnavi -->
        </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- end of menu -->

    ul {
        overflow:hidden;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    ul li {
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul li a {
        width:16.2%;
        /*164.6px;*/
        font-size:1em;
        line-height:1.8em;
        float:left;
        display:inline;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #menu ul li .subnavi {
        display:none;
        clear:both;
    }
    #menu ul li .subnavi ul {
        width:20em;
        background:#a0a0a0;
        list-style:none;
        margin:auto;
        line-height:2em;
        border:1px solid #a60000;
    }
    #menu ul li .subnavi ul li a {
        width:24em;
        line-height:1.8em;
        float:none;
        display:inline;
    }
    #menu ul li:hover .subnavi {
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: position relative on the outer li and position absolute on the .subnavi? So that it doesn't change anything in the positionning of the other elements.

Comment: Since you mentioned you're a beginner and @karthikr has already worked out a solution, here's a more generalised tip; your CSS selectors are overly specific. E.g. `#menu ul li .subnavi` could be written as `.subnavi`. This will cause you headaches later on when you need to override styles, and is less efficient for the browser to read. See: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/ for more info.
This doesn't have direct relevance to your original problem, but I thought it a useful tip to point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `clear:both` on `.subnav` and `position: absolute` on `.subnav ul`

```
#menu ul li .subnavi {
    display:none;
}
#menu ul li .subnavi ul {
    width:20em;
    background:#a0a0a0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:auto;
    line-height:2em;
    border:1px solid #a60000;
    position:absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCvct/3/)

Comment: thanks. Your answer helped me a lot. However, there is one more minor issue. I have to do a submenu for one more li. This is somewhere in the middle and the submenu comes below the first li.

Check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/mCvct/10/

Kindly help if possible.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mCvct/11/ That is driven by the css property `left:` you can either use `px` or `%` of width

Comment: not another level of nesting.. its just that the parent li for the submenu is somewhere in the middle. If I use your method, the submenu drops below the first parent li and not under its actual parent. If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/mCvct/10/ the submenu should come around 'services' and not under 'home'

Comment: sorry.. i read it wrong the first time. I just gave you the updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#menu ul li:hover .subnavi {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/orimed/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a absolute position to your `.subnavi` and position the top `ul` relative:

```
#menu ul li:hover .subnavi {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
}
ul {
    position: relative;
}
```

also add a little padding to your links will prevent the subnavi from closing before you actually reach it with the cursor:

```
ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pulleasy/mCvct/4/